# git shows old deleted branches in zsh TAB completion

Tags: git, zsh

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I don't know if this is a git "feature" or zsh, but I have a TON of delete branches that have been deleted stored somewhere if I tab over.

[image]

I have tried `prune` and that appears to not be doing want I intend.

The only branches I have locally are:

```
master
development
fix/root-cleanup
```

Comment: Do you have a zsh framework—e.g. oh my zsh shell? If yes, do you have some git module installed?  My guess is yes — and these are cached entries.

Comment: I have oh my zsh... this is an excellent clue. Where do they caches these entires?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the autocomplete tab was showing all the names of remote branches I had not done housekeeping on.

Found clues reading [this blog post](https://railsware.com/blog/2014/08/11/git-housekeeping-tutorial-clean-up-outdated-branches-in-local-and-remote-repositories/).

I was fixated on local and did not even consider if the plugin was pulling from the remote branches.

What's frustrating is that as in the screenshot all the branches without `origin/` were not local and not there. As soon as I started to delete the remote branches these ones disappeared as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe installing a  oh-my-zsh plugin like [diazod/git-prune](https://github.com/diazod/git-prune) would help apply the various [`git prune` aliases](https://github.com/diazod/git-prune/blob/458d7270270bfb376ee0a82e948db7410c4d5d73/git-prune.plugin.zsh#L1-L9).

That in turn should reduce the number of branches considerably.

---

Note that, with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), "git prune" has been added to the completion (in `contrib/`), which could be typed by end-users from the command line.

See [commit 81120a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81120a90aa32f545ce3b68f49d2877ccff29a6e3) (22 Jun 2020) by [John Lin (`johnlinp`)](https://github.com/johnlinp).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 65ffaca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65ffaca0e437b4b504fd5fbfe39e72331d7f7314), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bash-completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81120a90aa32f545ce3b68f49d2877ccff29a6e3): add git-prune into bash completion
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Lin</sup>

> Sometimes `git` would suggest the user to run `git prune` when there are too many unreachable loose objects.
> It's more user-friendly if we add [`git prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) into bash completion.

Comment: Enabled plugin, but did not remove these old deleted branches when I tab over.

Comment: @paulywill You enabled the plugin, but did you used its aliases?

Comment: sorry... I'm looking at the source you linked and not following. What would an example be?

Comment: @paulywill I mean: you have to execute those commands in order to delete the obsolete branches. At least this one: https://github.com/diazod/git-prune/blob/458d7270270bfb376ee0a82e948db7410c4d5d73/git-prune.plugin.zsh#L6-L8. `__prune_local_branches` and `__print_remote_branches`.